# hibernate extend more entities with a single metadata table

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have some entities in my Java web project, each entity is well defined in a specific table. Due to continuos customizations required on the entities model,

I've decided to create ONE MetaData entity and table to save additional attributes of all existing entities, as follows:
id, entityType, entityId, metaKey, metaValue

I'd use this MetaData entity to extend dynamically all the entities that need additional key/value attributes, referencing uniquely the entity with the entityName and the entityId.

Is there any smart way to to that? Right now, everytime I need to store an additional key/value to an entity, I call a specific method on the MetaDataDao to add this key/value, and to retrieve it once I load the entity data, I'd need a smarter way to manage storing/reading/attaching metas to the entity.

Hope my question is clear.
Best regards

Comment: Can you share what code you have written till now?

Comment: As entities are POJO's, you can extend one entity from another, and therefore inherit all the fields of the parent class.